# Angular - sum up numbers using a function and put it in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a function that will sum up some numbers from an incoming factory (and some from the client-side in real time), and will put the sum in the view. Totally stuck.

1 - First of all, I do not understand how to display in the view a variable that was assembled within a controller function.

So let's say I have something like:

```
$scope.total = function() {
    var totalNumber = 0;

}
```

How do I get the totalNumber to show in the view?

I assume after I get this, in order to sum up my factory data:

```
var revenues = [
            { amount: 1254 },
            { amount: 1654 },
            { amount: 33 },
            { amount: 543 }

    ];
```

I will have to do something like:

```
 $scope.total = function() {
 var totalNumber = 0;
    for(i=0; i<revenues.length; i++){
      totalNumber = totalNumber + revenues[i].amount
    }

    }
```

Is this correct? Will it update in real time if I dynamically change the revenue array?

Comment: You need to bind the variable to the scope. `$scope.totalNumber = 0`.

Comment: whatever the definition of total() you'll be able to display its value by simply doing  {{ total() }}

Comment: @whirlwin doesn't work.. shows nothing, and if I add var it throws an error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As promised, here is a different approach.  One that watches the `revenues` collection and updates a value every time it changes:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="SumCtrl">

  Total: {{total}}

  <input type="text" ng-model="newAmount" />
  <button ng-click="add(newAmount)">Add</button>

</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function SumCtrl($scope) {

  function total() {
    var totalNumber = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.revenues.length; i++){
      totalNumber = totalNumber + $scope.revenues[i].amount
    }

    return totalNumber;
  }

  $scope.revenues = [
    { amount: 1254 },
    { amount: 1654 },
    { amount: 33 },
    { amount: 543 }
  ];

  $scope.add = function(value) {
    $scope.revenues.push({ amount: parseInt(value) });
  }

  $scope.$watchCollection("revenues", function() {
    $scope.total = total();
  });

}
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution, however I can't get the $watchCollection method to work. I assume this might be my factory problem? Code: http://plnkr.co/edit/iDmphw

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?  I think that `$watchCollection` is a new thing.  It is in 1.2rc3.  I don't think it is 1.0.8.  If `$watchCollection` isn't available, you can use `$watch` with the "deep" flag set to true (though $watchCollection is better).  `$watch("revenues", function(){}, true);`

Comment: You are right. I need to update my version! (I am using a gem with Rails). Thank you for helping me out very much, maybe one day I will be as a smart Angular user as you are! :D

Comment: BTW: the total() function could be shortend to: `return $scope.revenues.reduce(function(prev, cur) { return prev + cur.amount; }, 0);`

Comment: @yankee Agreed.  Assuming, at least, that reduce is defined.  You'd need to polyfill for <IE9.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to solving this.  If you want a `total()` function, it goes like this:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="SumCtrl">

  Total: {{total()}}

  <input type="text" ng-model="newAmount" />
  <button ng-click="add(newAmount)">Add</button>

</div>
```

And here is the code:

```
function SumCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.revenues = [
    { amount: 1254 },
    { amount: 1654 },
    { amount: 33 },
    { amount: 543 }
  ];

  $scope.total = function() {
    var totalNumber = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.revenues.length; i++){
      totalNumber = totalNumber + $scope.revenues[i].amount
    }

    return totalNumber;
  }

  $scope.add = function(value) {
    $scope.revenues.push({ amount: parseInt(value) });
  }

}
```

The `total()` function will re-evaluate whenever the scope changes (a lot).  A better approach is to watch for changes to `revenues` and update a static value... I'll post that answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4df27XnXdz6yvW6V0dQT?p=preview)

There's more than one way to do this, and your controller might look different depending on how the data looks from your factory.

Edit: A couple of good answers were posted here while I was writing. This is similar to Brian's first approach.